# how to get the next year date from the date value stored in a php variable

Tags: php

I am trying to get the next year date from a php variable which holds the date value posted from a html form.
Below is the code

```
    $warranty_from = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['from_date']);
```

Say the $warranty_from holds the value 2013-06-04. I want to get the next year date i.e 
2014-06-04 and store into $warranty_to variable.
Searched lot over the net but couldnt find any resource related to my issue. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following should work:

```
$warranty_from = '2013-06-04';
$warranty_to = date('y-m-d', strtotime('+1 years', strtotime($warranty_from)));
```

Something like that should work

Comment: Thank You Neta for swift reply but the $newWarranty_date holds the value 71-01-01. I think its issue with php date format.

Comment: Can you print exactly what you get in your variable $warranty_from

Comment: $warranty_from contains 2013-06-04.I have used HTML5 date type in the html form.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
<?php
 $warranty_to = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+1 year', strtotime($warranty_from)));
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This was exact code

$newWarranty_date = date("Y-m-d",strtotime("+1 year",strtotime($warranty_from)));

Answer (score 0):

Calculations like this are trivial using the [DateTime](http://php.net/datetime) classes:-

```
$_POST['from_date'] = '2013-06-04';//Just for this example.
$warranty = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $_POST['from_date']);
$interval = new DateInterval('P1Y');
$warranty->add($interval);

echo $warranty->format('Y-m-d');
```

Will output:-

```
2014-06-04
```